# Why can't I run my codes in Python Shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wing-ide

```
def thisisfun(x,y,z):
    x=2
    y=3
    z=4 
    print('AHHHHA')
thisisfun(333,"annoy",2142125)
```

If it is with the last line, then after I clicked on `Execute Current File` it actually prints `AHHHHA`
But when I attempted to have thisisfun(333,"annoy",2142125) in Python Shell (without the last line), it says `name 'thisisfun' is not defined`
I dont know what happened to my WingIDE...:(
Help..

Comment: You need to execute the code in the context of your current session. Try using `import` with your file.

Comment: how you are calling the `.py` file?

Comment: I am new with Python so..... can you explain a liitle bit more on how to.... use import.... and i would also like to know why can't i execute it in python shell.. thanks

Comment: `from [filename] import [function]`

Comment: Seeing that you are new..., the suggested solutions says, create a .py file and save the its contents with the function definitions, i.e thisisfun.py file:, Then when in python shell, make sure you are running it in the same folder as the tisisfun.py file. The you can type `from thisisfun import thisisfun`. Then you can call the function as before `thisisfun(....)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute Current File runs that file outside of the debugger until it terminates.  This does not happen in the context of the Python Shell's runtime environment, but in a separate process.  If you want to work with this in the Python Shell then use Evaluate File in Python Shell in the Source menu.  After that, thisisfun is defined in the Python Shell's environment until you restart it from its Options menu.

Answer (score 2):

You need an empty line after your function definition or the parser gets confused:

```
def thisisfun(x,y,z):
    x=2
    y=3
    z=4 
    print('AHHHHA')

thisisfun(333,"annoy",2142125)
```

This makes it clear that the function call is not part of the function itself.

Comment: I mean... when I write thisisfun(333,"annoy",321323132414) (or whatever) in Python Shell section, it simply says that the function is not defined.

Comment: Why would this make any difference? The indentation makes it clear that the call is not part of the function.

Comment: @MarkRansom Just reporting how the `python` interactive console behaves, at least on my machine.